# Gatsby-aws user auth starter will not run, unhandled rejection

Tags: authentication, gatsby, aws-amplify

I cloned the `gatsby-starter-auth-aws-amplify` (found at https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/seabeams/gatsby-starter-auth-aws-amplify/), initialized the repo and installed all dependencies and continually get this error:

> UNHANDLED REJECTION Cannot create as TypeComposer the following value:
>   Date.

```
  Error: Cannot create as TypeComposer the following value: Date.

  - SchemaComposer.js:365 SchemaComposer.createTempTC
    [gatsby-starter-auth-aws-amplify]/[graphql-compose]/lib/SchemaComposer.js:365:    11

  - SchemaComposer.js:563 SchemaComposer.addAsComposer
    [gatsby-starter-auth-aws-amplify]/[graphql-compose]/lib/SchemaComposer.js:563:    27

  - schema-composer.js:35 createSchemaComposer
    [gatsby-starter-auth-aws-amplify]/[gatsby]/dist/schema/schema-composer.js:35:1    8

  - index.js:135 Object.build
    [gatsby-starter-auth-aws-amplify]/[gatsby]/dist/schema/index.js:135:26

  - index.js:418 async module.exports
    [gatsby-starter-auth-aws-amplify]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/index.js:418:3

  - develop.js:429 async module.exports
    [gatsby-starter-auth-aws-amplify]/[gatsby]/dist/commands/develop.js:429:7
```

Has anyone been through this? I found several instances of the error on github but the solutions that people found were too case-specific to apply to me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using YARN instead of NPM and it worked. Make sure you delete the node_modules and package.lock folder and file first.